# How to pass an audio stream to another page on the same website?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, web-audio-api

I want to stream an audio source from a website `/host` to another page `/listen` on the same website.

The principle seems to be a bit like an online radio, the mini player on YouTube or streaming services like Tidal or Spotify, where you can listen to the music while switching to another page on the website but the listener is never visiting `/host`. The listener hears what the host is saying on `/host`. A simplified graphics could look like this:

```
// ┌─────────────────────┐
// │                     │
// │  Host PC            │
// │                     │
// │  with microphone    │
// │                     │
// └───────────────┬─────┘
//                 │
// ┌───────────────▼─────┐
// │                     │
// │  Webserver          │
// │                     │
// └───────────────┬─────┘
//                 │
// ┌───────────────▼─────┐
// │                     │
// │  Admin panel page   │
// │                     │
// │  with input source  │ This page the host
// │                     │ is visiting.
// │  https://x.y/host   │
// │                     │
// └───────────────┬─────┘
//                 │
//                 │
// ┌───────────────▼─────┐
// │                     │ 
// │  User page          │
// │                     │
// │  listening to the   │ This page the listener
// │  stream             │ is visiting.
// │                     │
// │  https://x.y/listen │
// │                     │
// └─────────────────────┘
```

Via the `Web Audio API` I can setup an AudioContext and can add my microphone as a source via the `WebRTC API`, but I don't know how to connect it to another page:

```js
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

    const audioCtx = new AudioContext();

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then((stream) => {
        const microphone = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        microphone.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    });
```

**What would be the "best practice" way of achieving this expected behaviour?**

Comment: well you would use the [WebRTC API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API) and [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) - not sure exactly where you're stuck here

Comment: @skara9 yea, that's why I added these tags to my question.

Comment: i'm saying read the references if you want to know how to use them

Comment: @skara9 I've added an example of where it hangs for me :)

Comment: What is the relation between both pages? Is one the opener of the other or can they both be opened separately?

Comment: @Kaiido Ideally `/host` is used for the broadcaster and shouldn't be accessible by the user who listens to the audio. `/host` would be the "admin" panel.

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing the browser URL with [`History.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState). This prevents a full reloading of the web page, which preserves the recording/playing audio. This triggers the [`popstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event) event, which you can use to dynamically change certain content on the page while preserving other content (i.e. audio player) within the DOM.

**Examples**

- [https://cøder.com/static/70886780/host](https://xn--cder-gra.com/static/70886780/host)
- [https://cøder.com/static/70886780/listen](https://xn--cder-gra.com/static/70886780/listen)

**Web Server Config**

To intercept the first-load of the page, the backend web server needs to serve the same file for all or specific routes you define. For example, Nginx (serves above examples) is configured with:

```
location ~ ^(/static/70886780)/(host|listen|foo|bar)?$ {
  add_header cache-control no-cache;
  try_files $uri $1/index.html =404;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Wouldn't the user need to go to `/host` first to be able to hear the audio later on on `/listen`? Would your approach work, if the host is only on `/host` and the listener base just on `/listen`?

Comment: These tests work: [/host](https://xn--cder-gra.com/static/70886780/host) • [/listen](https://xn--cder-gra.com/static/70886780/listen)